# Whaimat? (Intentional Title)

Tags: riddle

I am helpful
I deliver cures to the sick
I deliver fuel to explosive chambers
I deliver molten material to create

I am harmful
I deliver death to criminals
I deliver irritation to the skin
I deliver addiction to the addicted

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are

> injection

I am helpful
I deliver cures to the sick

> cures delivered via injections

I deliver fuel to explosive chambers

> Fuel injectors

I deliver molten material to create

> injection molding

I am harmful
I deliver death to criminals

> death by injection

I deliver irritation to the skin

> Allergy tests by injecting irritants

I deliver addiction to the addicted

> drugs via injection

On the title

> am i is injected into what for whaimai

Comment: Not quite. Semi on the right track .

Comment: @ITAlex changed my answer slightly

Comment: Correct!. I deliver irritation to the skin was intended to be rot13 zbfdhvgbf vawrpgvat nagvpbnthynag but your answer works as well. (even though yours is technically beneficial.